# SubSonic + Oracle - what's better 2.2 or 3?

Tags: subsonic3, subsonic2.2

I've been using SubSonic 2 & 2.2 for a few years now with Sql Server.
For my new job I just recently used SubSonic 2.2 with Oracle and ran into a few small issues.

*Example: It could **not** find a column  in a table at run time even though it **found** it during the mapping.*

Does SubSonic 3 offer **better** Oracle support than 2.2 ?

**It seems that SubSonic 2.2 does not support Stored Procs
and  SubSonic 3 does not work at all for Oracle**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used subsonic 3 with oracle. But have used with sql server.

The [**Difference**](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Version_Difference) between subsonic versions.

It works great and with the new features.

You can find the [**oracle templates**](http://github.com/stimms/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/tree/master/TemplateProviders/) and other subsonic 3 docs [here](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Main_Page).

I would recommand to go for the [**subsonic 3**](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/3.0_Summary).

Answer (score 2):

I use SubSonic 2.2 because our Desktop app needs to support Windows 2000 so we are limited to .net 2.0

If you don't have to support .net 2.0 I would suggest using SubSonic 3 for new projects.

Advantages of SubSonic 3:

- T4 Engine for Template generation
- Simple Repository (if you want to use it)
- All the nice language sugar (linq, extension methods, expressions)
- better support for unit testing

and SubSonic 2 hasn't seen an update for over a year now.